# innerjoin query in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7

I am applying this query for below D6 query , not working ..dont know wat wrong i'm doing ....does innerjoin fails in some condition

```
$result = db_select('px_slides','s')
    ->join('node','n','s.vid = n.vid')
    ->fields('s',array('tissue_type','body_site'))
    ->fields('n',array('sticky','title'))
    ->condition('n.status','1','=')
    ->condition('s.cid','126','=')
    ->execute()->fetchObject();
```

drupal 6 query i have:

```
    $result = db_query('
  SELECT n.nid, n.vid, n.sticky, n.title, n.created, s.cid, s.ref_id, s.viewurl, s.specimen_type, s.tissue_type, s.body_site, s.test_type, s.algorithm, s.result 
  FROM {px_slides} s INNER JOIN {node} n ON n.vid = s.vid
  WHERE n.status = 1 ')->execute();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put your call to `->join()` on a separate line altogether, as it doesn't return the query object:

```
$query = db_select('px_slides','s')  
  ->fields('s',array('tissue_type','body_site'))
  ->fields('n',array('sticky','title'))
  ->condition('n.status','1','=')
  ->condition('s.cid','126','=');

$query->join('node','n','s.vid = n.vid');

$result = $query->execute()->fetchObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

The join method does not chain like that.  You will have to do something like:

```
$query = db_select('px_slides','s')
    ->join('node','n','s.vid = n.vid');
$query->fields('s',array('tissue_type','body_site'))
    ->fields('n',array('sticky','title'))
    ->condition('n.status','1','=')
    ->condition('s.cid','126','=');
$result = $query->execute()->fetchObject();
```

Also you can use the to string magic method to see the query it is going to execute.

```
$query->__toString();
```

Comment: Not worked, somehow putting the join statement after the fields and condition works

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$query = db_select('px_slides', 's');
$query->innerJoin('node,'n','s.vid = n.vid');
$query->fields('s',array('tissue_type','body_site'));
$query->fields('n',array('sticky','title'));
$query->condition('n.status','1');
$query->condition('s.cid','126');
$result= $query->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```